# Setting a prefix length hint (and similar DHCPv6) options with Dhcpcd

Tags: linux, ipv6, dhcpv6, dhcpcd

So I'm trying to get an ipv6 address from my ISP (Verizon in this case). With OPNSense I needed to set the wan interface to act as a dhcpv6 client and use a prefix size hint of 56 and ask only for a prefix. Now I'm trying to do it with just raw dhcpcd and there seems to be a dearth of documentation on how to set options like these. I even dug into the ipv6 rfcs and dhcpcd source to try and figure out what I'm suppose to do. Here's more or less the config I'ved ended up with:

```
duid
noipv6rs
nohook resolv.conf
nopv4ll

interface wan
  ipv6rs
  option dhcp6_26 56 # iaprefix option
  # also tried with:
  #option 26 56
  #option dhcp6_iaprefix 56 # not recognized by dhcpcd
  #option iaprefix 56 # not recognized by dhcpcd

  iaid 1
  ia_pd 1
```

The relevant logs are:

```
Jan 13 01:10:36 hermes dhcpcd[79635]: wan: IAID 00:00:00:01
Jan 13 01:10:36 hermes dhcpcd[79635]: wan: soliciting a DHCPv6 lease
...
Jan 13 01:10:36 hermes dhcpcd[79635]: wan: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jan 13 01:10:36 hermes dhcpcd[79635]: wan: Router Advertisement from fe80::56e0:32ff:fe75:3164
Jan 13 01:10:36 hermes dhcpcd[79635]: wan: no global addresses for default route
```

Anyone know how this is supposed to work?

Edit:
Here's a tcpdump of the wan icmp6 packets while dhcpcd is starting

```
sudo tcpdump -v -i wan icmp6
tcpdump: listening on wan, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
02:51:51.059467 IP6 (flowlabel 0xafbfa, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) hermes > ff02::2: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router solicitation, length 16
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
02:51:51.063387 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 24) fe80::56e0:32ff:fe75:3164 > ff02::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 24
    hop limit 64, Flags [managed], pref medium, router lifetime 1800s, reachable time 0ms, retrans timer 0ms
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
02:51:52.227093 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) 2600:4040:5120::1 > ff02::1:ff21:971f: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has hermes
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
02:51:52.227249 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) hermes > 2600:4040:5120::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, length 32, tgt is hermes, Flags [solicited, override]
      destination link-address option (2), length 8 (1): yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
02:51:57.349138 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) hermes > 2600:4040:5120::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has 2600:4040:5120::1
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
02:51:57.353447 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 24) 2600:4040:5120::1 > hermes: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, length 24, tgt is 2600:4040:5120::1, Flags [router, solicited]
```